# Akka Scala Camel. Exception handling

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka, scalaz, akka-camel

I have `akka camel-ftp` consumer. I would like to handle all exceptions in code (e.g.  Authentification Exception, or file on ftp cannot be read). I can see stacktrace in logs only and cannot handle it.
Maybe it is better to use `scalaz-camel`.

Additionally I would like to know when all files are processed and Actor idle untill next read ftp folder

```
class FtpWorkerActor() extends Consumer with ActorLogging {

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => /* handle files */

    case v: Any => /*never riched. but i need to understand if I have authentification issues etc*/

  }

  override def endpointUri: String = {
    val initDelay = 1000 // 1 second
    val otherOptions = s"disconnect=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&filter=#datFileFilter&delay=$processingDelay&initialDelay=$initDelay"
    s"ftp://$username@$ftpSourcePath?username=$username&password=$pass&$otherOptions"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run your Actor inside a supervisor and implement error handling there. Here's more documentation about that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fault-tolerance.html

In this case your supervisor will be able to catch all exceptions and decide what to do with the `FtpWorkerActor` - stop, restart, etc.

Comment: Hello @sap1ens. Thank you for the answer. I added `override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 2, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
      case v:GenericFileOperationFailedException =>
        log.warning(v.getMessage)
        Restart
      case _: Exception                    ⇒ Restart
    }
`  to the manager actor. but it doesn't work. I can see in log GenericFileOperationFailedException marked as warn (not error) by camel ftp. could you share some more details